# Magento2 - Remove Meta Keywords from all pages

Tags: magento2, seo

I'm currently developing some Magento2 themes. I noticed that in Magento2 Meta Keywords are still added. I want to remove this meta keywords from all pages, does anyone know the proper way to achieve this?

I did find meta.phtml, but I think this file is not used on a product page. Also the file Product/View.php adds the keywords with this function:

```
$this->pageConfig->setKeywords($keyword);
```

but I don't think it would be the prober way to extend the _prepareLayout function, right?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how is removing the meta keywords for your pages helpful to SEO?

Comment: Please see solution here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242517/remove-keywords-meta-tag-from-head-in-magento-2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just had to do the same and decided to just add a plugin after the getKeywords Method of the page config which returns an empty string. works great

di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config">
        <plugin name="removeMetaKeywords" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\PageConfig\RemoveMetaKeywords" sortOrder="9999"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin Class:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\PageConfig;

class RemoveMetaKeywords
{
    public function afterGetKeywords($subject, string $return)
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: and the entire `<meta name="keywords"...` is gone. :) Thanks

Comment: I get some error on some pages..

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Learning\FirstUnit\Plugin\PageConfig\RemoveMetaKeywords::afterGetKeywords() must be of the type string, null given, called in

Comment: Change class to: 

public function afterGetKeywords($subject, $return)
 {
  return (string)null;
 }
and the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Easy to remove or edit default meta keywords at admin configuration:

```
Store > Configuration > Design [General] - HTML Head
```

Comment: I want it removed from all pages, so also the category and product pages. When you create a product, the meta keywords will be automatically filled and added to the product page. So changing the default meta keywords will not do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just override the Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer

As this class's the method renderMetadata responsible for meta keywords render. On the override class's at that method add this condition:

```
 // add this code for stop render of keywords
    if ($name = 'keywords') {
        continue;
    }
```

Override function may be look

```
public function renderMetadata()
    {
        $result = '';
        foreach ($this->pageConfig->getMetadata() as $name => $content) {
            $metadataTemplate = $this->getMetadataTemplate($name);
            if (!$metadataTemplate) {
                continue;
            }
            // add this code for stop render of robot
            if ($name == 'keywords') {
                continue;
            }
            $content = $this->processMetadataContent($name, $content);
            if ($content) {
                $result .= str_replace(['%name', '%content'], [$name, $content], $metadataTemplate);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```