# Remove keywords meta tag from head in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, seo

It seems like having a keywords meta tag in your head is nowadays bad for SEO. Does anyone know how to remove the keywords meta tag from the head in Magento 2 in a professional way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a module with name **STech_Removekeywords** and create the files like below steps:

**Step 1:**
Create **registration.php** under:

> app/code/STech/Removekeywords/registration.php

with below content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'STech_Removekeywords',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:**
Create **module.xml** under:

> app/code/STech/Removekeywords/etc/module.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="STech_Removekeywords" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3:**
Create **di.xml** under:

> app/code/STech/Removekeywords/etc/di.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config">
        <plugin name="removeMetaKeywords" type="STech\Removekeywords\Plugin\PageConfig\RemoveMetaKeywords" sortOrder="9999"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step 4:**
Create **RemoveMetaKeywords.php** under:

> app/code/STech/Removekeywords/Plugin/PageConfig/RemoveMetaKeywords.php

with below content:

```
<?php
namespace STech\Removekeywords\Plugin\PageConfig;

class RemoveMetaKeywords
{
    public function afterGetKeywords($subject, string $return)
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Run setup upgrade, di compile and other required commands and test.

Comment: Did you put downvote?

Comment: I've put upvote of course

Answer (score -2):

Simple just remove the meta tag from the vendor\magento\module-cms\view\frontend\templates\meta.phtml  Or app\design\frontend\/\Magento_Cms\templates\meta.phtml

```
<?php if ($pageData->getPageMetaKeywords()): ?>
       <meta name="keywords" content="<?= /* @noEscape */ $pageData->getPageMetaKeywords() ?>"/>
<?php endif; ?>
```