# How to remove meta title from head in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, meta-tags, meta-title

I need to remove meta title from header in all pages.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Oneplus One"/>
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
<!-- I need to remove meta title -->
<meta name="title" content="Oneplus One"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width/>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
<title>Oneplus One</title>
```

I have created module **RemoveMetaTitle**.

di.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config">
        <plugin name="unsetMetaTitle" type="Vendor\RemoveMetaTitle\Plugin\PageConfig\UnsetMetaTitle" sortOrder="9999"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin/PageConfig/UnsetMetaTitle.php :

```
namespace Vendor\RemoveMetaTitle\Plugin\PageConfig;

class UnsetMetaTitle
{
    public function afterGetMetaTitle($subject, $return)
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

**afterGetMetaTitle** seems to be not even executed.

Comment: check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96051/magento2-remove-meta-keywords-from-all-pages?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config">
        <plugin name="unsetMetaTitle" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\PageConfig\unsetMetaTitle" sortOrder="9999"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

PageConfig class

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\PageConfig;

class unsetMetaTitle
{
    public function afterGetMetaTitle($subject, string $return)
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: This class is not even executed. Are you sure the plugin name "unsetMetaTitle" is correct? Because I tried "removeMetaKeywords", the class is executed.

Comment: any plugin name will work. so 'unsetMetaTitle' is correct one.

Comment: I tried to add function "afterGetKeywords", it is executed. But "afterGetMetaTitle" is not executed.

Comment: Are you sure it is "afterGetMetaTitle"?

Comment: share your code in question

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same problem which I fixed by creating a custom module.

The title meta tag is being generated from magento framework. You can override the function by creating a custom module like I did.

> 1. /app/code/Mediajedi/CustomHead/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mediajedi_CustomHead" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> 2. /app/code/Mediajedi/CustomHead/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mediajedi_CustomHead',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 3. /app/code/Mediajedi/CustomHead/etc/di.xml

```
<config>
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer" type="Mediajedi\CustomHead\View\Page\Config\AfCustomrenderer" />
</config>
```

> 4. /app/code/Mediajedi/CustomHead/View/Page/Config/AfCustomrenderer.php

```
<?php

namespace Mediajedi\CustomHead\View\Page\Config;

use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config;

class AfCustomrenderer extends \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer
{
    /**
     * Returns metadata template
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return bool|string
     */
    protected function getMetadataTemplate($name)
    {
        if (strpos($name, 'og:') === 0) {
            return '<meta property="' . $name . '" content="%content"/>' . "\n";
        }

        switch ($name) {
            case Config::META_CHARSET:
                $metadataTemplate = '<meta charset="%content"/>' . "\n";
                break;

            case Config::META_CONTENT_TYPE:
                $metadataTemplate = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="%content"/>' . "\n";
                break;

            case Config::META_X_UI_COMPATIBLE:
                $metadataTemplate = '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="%content"/>' . "\n";
                break;

            case Config::META_MEDIA_TYPE:
                $metadataTemplate = false;
                break;

            default:
              if($name != 'title'){
                $metadataTemplate = '<meta name="%name" content="%content"/>' . "\n";
              } else{
                  $metadataTemplate = '';
              }
                break;
        }
        return $metadataTemplate;
    }
}
```

You can see in the default case in AfCustomrenderer.php file, we are checking for title meta tag and assigning an empty value to $metadataTemplate which returns an empty value and results in removing of the title meta tag from the head.

> Please note that "Mediajedi" is the vendor name and "CustomHead" is
>   our module name. You can change them to yours.

Answer (score 0):

**Just create a new module for this:**

> add below code in di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config">
    <plugin name="removeMetaKeywords" type="Vendor\Namespace\Plugin\PageConfig\RemoveMetaKeywords" sortOrder="9999"/>
</type>
```

> add below code in Vendor\Namespace\Plugin\PageConfig\RemoveMetaKeywords

```
<?php
    declare(strict_types = 1);
    namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\PageConfig;
    class RemoveMetaKeywords
    {
       public function afterGetKeywords($subject, string $return)
       {
         return '';
       }
    }
 ?>
```

> and it will remove the entire `<meta name="keywords" />` from all the pages.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking to remove title meta.

Comment: can you set custom meta title from here?